# Convert string S to another string T by performing exactly K operations (append to / delete from the end of the string S)

Tags: string, algorithm, logic

I am trying to solve a problem. But I am missing some corner case. Please help me. The problem statement is:

You have a string, `S` , of lowercase English alphabetic letters. You can perform two types of operations on `S`:

1. Append a lowercase English alphabetic letter to the end of the string.
2. Delete the last character in the string. Performing this operation on an empty string results in an empty string.

Given an integer, `k`, and two strings, `s` and `t` , **determine whether or not you can convert `s` to `t` by performing `exactly k` of the above operations on `s`.**

If it's possible, print Yes; otherwise, print No.

```
Examples 
Input           Output

hackerhappy     Yes
hackerrank
9

5 delete operations (h,a,p,p,y) and 4 append operations (r,a,n,k)

aba             Yes
aba
7

4 delete operations (delete on empty = empty) and 3 append operations
```

I tried in this way (C language):

```
int sl = strlen(s); int tl = strlen(t); int diffi=0;  

int i;
for(i=0;s[i]&&t[i]&&s[i]==t[i];i++); //going till matching
diffi=i;  

((sl-diffi+tl-diffi<=k)||(sl+tl<=k))?printf("Yes"):printf("No");
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thank You

Comment: So what is your problem? Does your algorithm work? If not, find an counter example. Try your algorithm a) by hand on a peace of paper or b) use a debugger to find out where the algorithm goes wrong.

Comment: @MrSmith42, I tried, but I am missing some corner case, I am not getting

Comment: where is the example for the 'corner case' and what was the result of the debugging for it?

Comment: it says *exactly* k operations, so you should return FALSE for (abc,abd,3)

Comment: @MrSmith42, I am solving this on a online programming platform, I don't know the testcases. ok, I will try some more test cases, and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the remaining operations to divide in 2, because you need to just add and remove letters to waste the operations.

so maybe:

// c language  - strcmp(s,t) returns 0 if s==t.

```
if(strcmp(s,t))
    ((sl-diffi+tl-diffi<=k && (k-(sl-diffi+tl-diffi))%2==0)||(sl+tl<=k))?printf("Yes"):printf("No");
else 
   if(sl+tl<=k||k%2==0) printf("Yes"); else printf("No");
```

Comment: Note that the divide by 2 rule doesn't apply if `k > strlen(s) + strlen(t)`, because when you have remove all characters you can waste an odd number of operations using the delete from empty string rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one more way using binary search.

Take the string of smaller length and take sub-string(pattern) of length/2.

1.Do a binary search(by character) on both of the string if u get a match append length/4 more character to the pattern if it matches add more by length/2^n else append one character to the original(pattern of length/2) and try .

2.If u get a mismatch for pattern of length/2 reduce length of the pattern to length/4 and if u get a match append next character .

Now repeat the steps 1 and 2

If n1+n2 <= k then the answer is Yes
else the answer is no

Example:

```
s1=Hackerhappy
s2=Hackerrank
pattern=Hacker // length = 10 (s2 is smaller and length of s2=10 length/2 =5)
//Do a binary search of the pattern you will get a match by steps 1 and 2
n1 number of mismatched characters is 5 
n2 number of mismatched characters is 4

Now n1+n2<k // its because we will need to do these much operation to make these to equal.
So Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all cases:

```
int sl = strlen(s); int tl = strlen(t); int diffi=0;  

int i,m;
for(i=0;s[i]&&t[i]&&s[i]==t[i];i++); //going till matching
diffi=i; 
m = sl+tl-2*diffi;

((k>=m&&(k-m)%2==0)||(sl+tl<=k))?printf("Yes"):printf("No");
```